# Javascript p5 Unable to draw line between two points

Tags: javascript, p5.js

In javascript, using p5, I want to draw a line between two points, set by the mouse. I'm using an array to store the mouse positions, then draw the line. However, I get a weird output when I log the array in the console.

[image: This is the array in the console. The first two and last two elements are the mouse positions.]

What would the "*empty x 2*" mean?
This is my code:

```
function mouseClicked(){
pointSize = slider.value();
stroke(color_picker.value());
strokeWeight(pointSize);
point(mouseX, mouseY);

if(selection === "line"){
   line_points.push(mouseX, mouseY);
   console.log(line_points);
   console.log(line_points.length);

    if(line_points.length = 4){
        line(line_points[0],line_points[1],line_points[2],line_points[3]);
        line_points = [];
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: line_points.length = 4 is this intentional are you trying to compare the length?

Comment: Is there a typo here? `line_point[0]` instead of `line_points[0]`?

Comment: I’m using line_points.length so if both mouse positions (x and y axis each) are present in the array then it will draw the line, then reset the array. Also, even after correcting the typo, it still didn’t work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue in the code is the conditional

```
 if(line_points.length = 4)
```

should be

```
if(line_points.length ==== 4)
```

as we want to compare length to 4. The original code sets the length of the array to 4 which leaves the array with some empty positions, thus producing the empty slots message when the array is output to the console.

```js
function setup(){
    const cnv = createCanvas(200, 200);

}
var line_points = [];
function draw(){

}

function mouseClicked(){
   stroke(0);
   point(mouseX, mouseY);
   line_points.push(mouseX, mouseY);
   console.log(line_points);
   console.log(line_points.length);

    if(line_points.length === 4){
        line(line_points[0],line_points[1],line_points[2],line_points[3]);
        line_points = [];
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.8.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```